# Correr publish de una aplicación C# MVC desde consola cmd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

tengo el publish de un proyecto Web MVC en C#, y estoy buscando la forma de correrlo por medio de línea de comandos.

y 2. ¿Como es que visual studio levanta los servicios para correr las aplicaciones web sin tener el IIS configurado?

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que tu configuracion de publicaciones ya se encuentra bien digamos que tienes mas de un ambiente, aqui un ejemplo (release)

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o C:\MyWebs\test
```

claro es para .NET core